# delete "column does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I'm trying to execute a very simple delete query in Postgres

Query:

```
delete from "Tasks" where id = "fc1f56b5-ff41-43ed-b27c-39eac9354323";
```

Result:

```
ERROR:  column "fc1f56b5-ff41-43ed-b27c-39eac9354323" does not exist
LINE 1: delete from "Tasks" where id = "fc1f56b5-ff41-43ed-...
```

I have a simple table with a record where the id is that value. Why does it thing that `"fc1f56b5-ff41-43ed-b27c-39eac9354323"` is the column name?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that you are using double quotes (`"`) and single quotes (`'`) interchangeably. SQL treats what's inside double quotes "" as an identifier (i.e., table name, proc name, column name, etc.), character constants need to be [enclosed in single quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

You can say:

```
delete from "Tasks" where id = 'fc1f56b5-ff41-43ed-b27c-39eac9354323'
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `set quoted_identifier` "in SQL" or Postgres

Comment: Thanks for the edit. On my MSSQL, if I set quoted_identifier to OFF, I can then do this: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= "someValue"

Comment: Well, that is something specific to Microsoft SQL Server - that is neither "SQL" nor is it valid for Postgres

Comment: The best answer that I needed. Thx a lot @JustAPup